# playframework 1.2.5 session is different in plugins vs. in code

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Why does the session in playframework 1.2.5 change from the plugin and then when the session is finally saved.  My plugin fails to work because of this.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be a bug in ActionInvoker.java

moving this code up a few lines fixes the issue(I hope it doesn't break anything else though)..

```
    if(request.resolved) {
        //Well, I moved this here as resolve is being called twice and blowing away the first created session...
        //I wonder why they put this below
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your explanation where the code lies and where you moved it to. If you save the session in the **rawInvocation** method for example, the session will be saved as part of the HTTP Thread and not the action invoker thread.

When the action invoker thread execute it will read the session from the cookie again and you sill lose any change you might have done to the session prior to that.

Comment: If you search for the first instance of request.resolved in ActionInvoker.java, you will see that if statement is BELOW the creation of the session which blew my first session away.  My change below fixed the issue.

Comment: I think it would be good to explain briefly what and where you're doing with the plugin/session. The plugin code is invoked at different stages and different threads so it's hard to work out what you refer to without it.

Comment: actually, the plugins are invoked on the same thread as I stepped through it and my plugin was adding a one thing to the session which was never saved to the cookie until I applied my fix above....it is working now with the fix.